# Gdbserver and idapro

Tags: ida, android, gdb

I would like to reverse a file so of an apk using idapro (on windows) and gdbserver(on remote target device) . I arrived until the attach of the running process. But after? Is there a tutorial explaining the procedure? Which commands accepts idapro gdb monitor? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any gdb command for debugging. After IDA attached to the remote gdb server, the running process will be stopped at some random position. If you know where you want to stop, follow the following steps:

- go to this position (by pressing G),
- set a breakpoint and
- continue the execution.

After a while your process will stop at the breakpoint, if you place the breakpoint in an address, which will be executed.